# If a polynomial equation is satisfied by a matrix .Is the Polynomial it's characteristics equation????

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

If a n order square matrix Satisfy any Arbitrary n degree Polynomial..
Can we say it is the character Polynomial Of the Matrix..???

If NO then what is necessary condition for the Matrix or Polynomial to be The statement true????

Comment: Did you check this for $1\times 1$ matrices before you asked?

Comment: 1×1 are you talking about zero matrix

Comment: Not necessarily. The chararacteristic polynomial of $[a]$ is $X-a$. Yet $a$ satisfies every polynomial $(X-a)g(X)$, and no others. So there's your answer for $1\times 1$ matrices. Now @Stinking Bishop has explained that this generalises to $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: Every matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial but not vice versa. So, your statement is not true in general.

Answer (score 3):

No. If $p(A)=0$ then the only thing you can say is that $\mu_A\mid p$, where $\mu_A$ is the *minimal* polynomial of $A$. In particular, the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A$ has the same property $\chi_A(A)=0$, so $\mu_A\mid\chi_A$.

There isn't much more you can say in general. However, for a lot of matrices (especially those that have all the eigenvalues different) you have $\mu_A=\chi_A$ so in that case you can replace $\mu_A\mid p$ with $\chi_A\mid p$.

In the latter case, you can still *not* conclude that $\chi_A=p$, though, without an additional information about $p$. For example, if, as in your example, $A$ is of order $n$ (so the degree of $\chi_A$ is $n$) and $p$ is also of degree $n$, then knowing $p\mid\chi_A$ lets you conclude that $p$ is "essentially" the same as $\chi_A$ (i.e. they are the same up to a constant multiplier).

Comment: Can you provide one example where minimal Polynomial is same as characteristics Polynomial.but there exist Another Polynomial of same degree which is satisfied by the Matrix

Comment: @Soubhagya I cannot. If $p\mid\mu_A=\chi_A$ and $p$ and $\chi_A$ are of the same degree $n$, then they are essentially the same polynomial (up to a constant factor). I have fixed my answer to account for that case.